# How to make a multi-dimensional column into a single valued vector for training data in sklearn pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a data set in which certain column is a combination of couple of independent values, as in the example below:

```
id        age        marks
1          5          3,6,7
2          7          1,2
3          4          34,78,2
```

Thus the column by itself is composed of multiple values, and I need to pass the vector into a machine learning algorithm , I **cannot** really combine the values to assign a single value like :

```
3,6,7 => 1
1,2 => 2
34,78,2 => 3
```

making my new vector as

```
id        age        marks
1          5          1
2          7          2
3          4          3
```

and then subsequently pass it to the algorithm , as the number of such combination would be infinite and also that might not really capture the real meaning of the data.

how to handle such situation where individual feature is a combination of multiple features.

Note :

the values in column marks are just examples, it could be anything a list of values.  it could be list of integer or list of string , string composed of multiple stings separated by commas

Comment: what is `3,6,7` - a string or a list of integers?

Comment: If this a question for Stackoverflow, or perhaps a mathematics or statistics forum? As for how to take a single column and perform a function on it, assuming you data is in a `pandas.DataFrame`  object as `df` then try `df['marks'] = df['marks'].apply(lambda x: some_function(x), axis=1)`.

Comment: @MaxU it could be anything a list of values. the data i have put up is just and example , it could be list of integer or list of string , string composed of multiple stings separated by commas

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** I think we can use [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) in this case:

assuming we have the following DF:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
   id  age        marks
0   1    5    [3, 6, 7]
1   2    7       [1, 2]
2   3    4  [34, 78, 2]
3   4   11    [3, 6, 7]

In [34]: %paste
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer

vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), stop_words=None, tokenizer=TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize)

X = vect.fit_transform(df.marks.apply(' '.join))

r = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vect.get_feature_names())
## -- End pasted text --
```

Result:

```
In [35]: r
Out[35]:
   1  2  3  34  6  7  78
0  0  0  1   0  1  1   0
1  1  1  0   0  0  0   0
2  0  1  0   1  0  0   1
3  0  0  1   0  1  1   0
```

**OLD answer:**

you can first convert your list to string and then [categorize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) it:

```
In [119]: df
Out[119]:
   id  age        marks
0   1    5    [3, 6, 7]
1   2    7       [1, 2]
2   3    4  [34, 78, 2]
3   4   11    [3, 6, 7]

In [120]: df['new'] = pd.Categorical(pd.factorize(df.marks.str.join('|'))[0])

In [121]: df
Out[121]:
   id  age        marks new
0   1    5    [3, 6, 7]   0
1   2    7       [1, 2]   1
2   3    4  [34, 78, 2]   2
3   4   11    [3, 6, 7]   0

In [122]: df.dtypes
Out[122]:
id          int64
age         int64
marks      object
new      category
dtype: object
```

this will also work if `marks` is a column of strings:

```
In [124]: df
Out[124]:
   id  age    marks
0   1    5    3,6,7
1   2    7      1,2
2   3    4  34,78,2
3   4   11    3,6,7

In [125]: df['new'] = pd.Categorical(pd.factorize(df.marks.str.join('|'))[0])

In [126]: df
Out[126]:
   id  age    marks new
0   1    5    3,6,7   0
1   2    7      1,2   1
2   3    4  34,78,2   2
3   4   11    3,6,7   0
```

Comment: but dont i loose the real values and the combinations are infinite

Comment: This answer is accurate and useful.  Despite the down vote, this should be considered as a viable solution.

Comment: @JibinMathew, i just updated my answer - please check

Comment: ya this seems viable, but wont it increase the number of features may be to a large extend ?

Comment: @JibinMathew, well, you either want to feed all features to your machine learning algorithm or you want to use just some of them (so you can filter them using customized `CountVectorizer(vocabulary=..., tokenizer=...)`). At the end you should decide which features are important for you...

Comment: @MaxU if the field marks are supposed to hold continuous values, and as per the solution the new features are 1,2,3,34,6,7,78 and what happens a new value comes in say 10 in the input prediction vector . wont this solution fail?

Comment: @JibinMathew, it should be pretty easy to test it, right?

Comment: it fails when new values come in

Answer (score 1):

Tp access them as either `[[x, y, z], [x, y, z]]` or `[[x, x], [y, y], [z, z]]` (whatever is most appropriate for the function you need to call) then use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3, 4], b=[3, 4, 3, 4], c=[[1,2,3], [1,2], [], [2]]))
df.values
zip(*df.values)

where
>>> df

   a  b          c
0  1  3  [1, 2, 3]
1  2  4     [1, 2]
2  3  3         []
3  4  4        [2]
>>> df.values

array([[1, 3, [1, 2, 3]],
       [2, 4, [1, 2]],
       [3, 3, []],
       [4, 4, [2]]], dtype=object)
>>> zip(*df.values)

[(1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 3, 4), ([1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [], [2])]
```

To convert a column try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2], b=[3, 4], c=[[1,2,3], [1,2]]))
df['c'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x))
```

before:

```
>>> df
   a  b          c
0  1  3  [1, 2, 3]
1  2  4     [1, 2]
```

after:

```
>>> df
   a  b    c
0  1  3  2.0
1  2  4  1.5
```

Comment: This answer is inaccurate as many different combinations can have the same mean. By stating (replacing the lambda function with whatever function you need) you are ignoring the most difficult part of the problem.  Let me know if you update the answer and I'm happy to remove the down-vote.

Comment: @piRSquared, thanks for pointing that out. Hopefully the following is more useful for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can `pd.factorize` `tuples`
Assuming `marks` is a list

```
df

   id  age        marks
0   1    5    [3, 6, 7]
1   2    7       [1, 2]
2   3    4  [34, 78, 2]
3   4    5    [3, 6, 7]
```

Apply `tuple` and factorize

```
df.assign(new=pd.factorize(df.marks.apply(tuple))[0] + 1)

   id  age        marks  new
0   1    5    [3, 6, 7]    1
1   2    7       [1, 2]    2
2   3    4  [34, 78, 2]    3
3   4    5    [3, 6, 7]    1
```

---

***setup `df`***

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 5, ['3', '6', '7']],
        [2, 7, ['1', '2']],
        [3, 4, ['34', '78', '2']],
        [4, 5, ['3', '6', '7']]
    ], [0, 1, 2, 3], ['id', 'age', 'marks']
)
```